# How to get pixel color in Android?

Tags: android

I have set a PNG image(image having transparent background) as button background, When I touch the button it shows me X-coordinate and Y-coordinate of the button’s touched position but, I want to know pixel color of the touched position of the button.

Actually I want to know whether the touched position is transparent area of the button or colored area of the button.  You can check my code that I have developed for this purpose.  Please help me in this respect; your help would be cordially appreciated.

```
 button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {

                int x_coordinate  = (int)event.getX(); 
                int y_coordinate = (int)event.getY(); 

            //int color = Bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
                {
                }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
                {
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can get the Bitmap with the *BitmapFactory* like this:
`Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pic1);`

Now you have the Bitmap. On this Bitmap, you can call the function `getPixel(int x, int y)` to get the Color of this Pixel.
I guess you then can get the alpha from that Color..

See the following links for further information:

- [Bitmap Example](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/Working-with-Images-in-Googles-Android-3748281.htm)
- [getPixel(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel%28int,%20int%29)
- [Android Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)

Comment: My app keeps FC, because my image is smaller than my background. Can you please help?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by FC. But if you resize your Image, you could enable drawing cache and then call [getDrawingCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache()) and work on that Bitmap instead.

Comment: Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420278/how-to-keep-an-image-inside-layout-on-drag

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Drawable drawable = button.getBackground();
Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
int color = bmp.getPixel(x_coordinate, y_coordinate);
```

Comment: This Line: Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();  shows BitmapDrawable cannot be resolved

Comment: @user1703737, Did you import the package?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.picture);
    int color=bitmap.getPixel(x_coordinate, y_coordinate);
```

Use this color in your if statements to do the required operations