# How to get pixel colour on screen (not using images) on Android?

Tags: android, screen, pixel

I am developing a app to help with caligraphy. I intent to put the Letter/character on screen, and I want to know if the place where the user touches is inside or outside the letter area. Also, I want to be able to change the letter to another one and be able to obtain the same information and so on.

So I want to get the pixel colour of the screen on Android, but I am using a TextView (white screen, black letter), so I cannot do it using getDrawable (as there's a lot of examples found here). So how can I do it properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get pixel color in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544609/how-to-get-pixel-color-in-android)

Comment: what you mean by screen? you mean home page? background? 
If you want to do it when other apps open you need to do it as Service and set windowManager in it then set touch listener and return true.